# SQL Server Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I am getting this error when executing a `stored procedure` that I have created

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UDP_INITIAL_CUSTOMER_DIM_POPULATION, Line 28
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The code for the procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UDP_INITIAL_CUSTOMER_DIM_POPULATION
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    EXEC UDP_REMOVE_NULLS_FROM_CUSTOMER_STG

    INSERT INTO dbo.customer_dim(customer_no, first_name, middle_name, last_name,
                                 street_number, street_name, po_address, zip_code, city,
                                 region, country)
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            CAST(customer_no AS VARCHAR),
            first_name,
            middle_name,
            last_name,
            street_number,
            street_name,
            po_address,
            zip_code,
            city,
            region,
            country
        FROM 
            dbo.customer_stg

    PRINT 'Initial customer data in place!'
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

and the code to create the `customer_dim` table is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UDP_CREATE_CUSTOMER_DIM
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('customer_dim', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE customer_dim
    END

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customer_dim]
    (
        [customer_sk] INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        [customer_no] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [first_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [middle_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [last_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [customer_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [street_number] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [street_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [customer_address] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [po_address] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [zip_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [city] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [region] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [country] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [effective_date] DATE NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
        [expiry_date] DATE NULL DEFAULT '999-12-31'
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END
```

I have tried looking for a solution but because I am not trying to do anything on the date or time I cannot find anything that is making sense to me.

Comment: I think it's the default value for `expiry_date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is caused by the default value for the `expiry_date`. Running

```
SELECT CAST('999-12-31'AS DATE)
```

will produce an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

What you want is

```
[expiry_date] DATE NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing string to date conversion in SQL 2017 and it properly handles strings in m/d/yyyy format with single and double digit days or months and two or four digit years.  For example, the following strings converted cleanly:

```
2/6/2012
1/20/2020
12/21/2017
6/14/21
```

In my case I found the problem to be a record with a value of '5/15/161'.  To find the bad data, use the ISDATE() function.  In my case:

```
SELECT [EMPLOYER NUMBER],[PLAN],[EMPLOYER NAME],[LAST UPDATED]
FROM [CONTACT NAME ADDRESS]
where [last updated] is not null
  and isdate([last updated]) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value should be converted to the data type of column by query executor.

Date data type requires data in " **YYYY**-mm-dd" fromat

Luke problem is with your default vale for date data type.

While sql is trying to convert /cast  yyy-mm-dd it fails to convert it to date